# Sleuth R Error: System is computationally singular

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am working with Kallisto and Sleuth to analyze some RNA seq data. I have a control set of macula data and a set of macula data with AMD. I am trying to analyze differential gene expression between the two sets.

```
 Design table:
 sample Tissue  Condition
 AMD_macula.11  Macula  AMD
 AMD_macula.12  Macula  AMD
 AMD_macula.14  Macula  AMD
 AMD_macula.17  Macula  AMD
 AMD_macula.18  Macula  AMD
 AMD_macula.19  Macula  AMD
 ctrl_macula.10 Macula  nodisease
 ctrl_macula.13 Macula  nodisease
 ctrl_macula.15 Macula  nodisease
 ctrl_macula.16 Macula  nodisease
 ctrl_macula.4  Macula  nodisease
 ctrl_macula.6  Macula  nodisease
```

I have created my sleuth object and now I am trying to fit the models so I can run linear regression and wald tests.

```
 so <- sleuth_fit(so, ~sample + Condition,'full')
 so <- sleuth_fit(so, ~Tissue, 'Tissue')
 models(so)
```

When running these, I cannot get past creating the first model because I am getting this error that is saying that the system is computationally singular.

```
 > so <- sleuth_fit(so, ~sample + Condition,'full')
 Error in solve.default(t(X) %*% X) : 
 system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.82836e-18
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I believe something is wrong with my design table, but I cannot think of how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance of dreaded [linear combination](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#model-matrix-not-full-rank) problem. In your case `Condition` is a linear combination of `sample.` The solution is to remove sample from the design since you don't have any replicates of this factor and probably aren't very interested in it anyway. `Tissue` only has one level, so it's pointless to include it as well. What you want is:

```
so <- sleuth_fit(so, ~ Condition, 'full')
so <- sleuth_fit(so, ~1, 'reduced')
```

See [here](https://pachterlab.github.io/sleuth_walkthroughs/trapnell/analysis.html) for an example of analysing a dataset with the same design.